# Get columns from table based on condition

Tags: mysql

I am using stored procedure. I am passing some input parameter to stored procedure like p_type. Based on this condition i need to get either 1 column or 3 column as output

like

```
select
a_orderid                 AS OrderId,
t_logisticpartner.a_name  AS Logistics,
t_shipment.a_shipmentid   AS ShipmentId
from order some join comitions;
```

If p_type is 1 then i need all 3 columns or else just orderid column. I need to have aliases also.

Answer (score 0):

Two MySQL solutions:

1. Write big switch with all possible SELECT queries using CASE or IF statements.
2. Construct result SELECT statement, and then execute it using MySQL prepared statements.